# PostgreSQL: Do I need to lock table to avoid concurrency errors during update that use a subquery to find the index o update in a JSONB array?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, jsonb

Assuming I want to update a JSONB column `contacts` (array of objects) in a `customers` table, and I want to update a value of an object inside an array based on its index thanks to a subquery, **do I need to lock the table** from update during the execution to avoid concurrency problems?

In other words, **could the table be altered** between my two query execution, and thus the index I selected thanks to the subquery would be obsolete?

```sql
with contact_email as (
    select ('{' || index - 1 || ', value}')::text[] as path from customers
    cross join jsonb_array_elements(contacts) with ordinality arr(contact, index)
    where contact->>type = 'email' and name = 'john'
)
update customers
set contacts = jsonb_set(contacts,contact_email.path,'"john@example.com"', false)
from contact_email
where and name = 'john'

-- `customers` table has a `name` column and a `contacts` column (jsonb)
-- `contacts` column contains things like `[{"type":"email","value":"x@y.z", …}]`
```

In the example above, if the array in the `contacts` column is altered between the table reading (subquery) and the update (main query), then the index selected would become wrong: then I would update the wrong array entry.

If something is unclear I can edit my question and add more details.

Comment: I can see only one query, not two. The data is seen as unchanging, unless you explicitly lower the isolation level of the session. See [13.2. Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/transaction-iso.html)

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you! You mean that the whole query (including its subquery, since it's just one query) locks the row then release it, so it can't be altered during the execution of the query (which contains a subpart)? Feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both parts of the query will see the same snapshot of the database, so the data are always consistent.

If some concurrent transaction changes the row between the time it is read and the time it is written, the outcome depends on your isolation level:

- if you are running with the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation, the update will either overwrite that change or do nothing (the latter if `name` has changed)
- if you are running with `REPEATABLE READ` or higher, you will get a *serialization error* and have to repeat the statement